# Avoid killing learnable parameters when transforming input into intervals

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to make a model using Pytorch which is training and transforming a set of coordinates, and then is downsampled using the model below. However, when I'm making the input coordinates into result_tensor, the trainable parameters from transformed_coordinates get killed. This happens when I define within_interval. Does anyone know why this happens and if there is a better way of doing this?

```
class Class(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_classes=2):
        super(Class, self).__init__()

        # number of output channels
        dim = 3
        
        self.dim = dim

        # Fully Connected
        self.fully_net = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(dim, 64),
            torch.nn.Tanh(),
            torch.nn.Linear(64, n_classes),
        )

        # Global Average Pooling
        self.global_avg_pool = torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool1d(1)
        
    def forward(self, input: torch.Tensor, transformed_coordinates):
        r_max = 20
        r_min = 0
        
        radius = transformed_coordinates
        
        intensity = input
        
       
        # Defining the number of intervals
        num_intervals = self.dim
        
        # Creating intervals from radius values
        intervals = torch.linspace(r_min, r_max, num_intervals + 1)

        # Initialize the result tensor
        result_tensor = torch.empty(0)

        # Loop through figures and radius intervals
        for figure_idx in range(len(intensity)):
            class_tensor = torch.empty(0)
            for interval_idx in range(num_intervals):
                # Find pixels that fall within the radius interval
                within_interval = torch.logical_and(
                    radius > intervals[interval_idx],
                    radius <= intervals[interval_idx + 1]
                )
                
                within_interval = within_interval.int()
                class_tensor = torch.cat((class_tensor, within_interval), -1)
                
                # Assign the sum to the result tensor
            result_tensor = torch.cat((result_tensor, class_tensor))
        
       
        result_tensor = result_tensor*intensity
        result_tensor = result_tensor.permute(0,2,1)
        result_tensor = self.global_avg_pool(result_tensor)
        result_tensor = result_tensor.permute(0,2,1)
        x = self.fully_net(result_tensor)
                
        return x.squeeze(1)
```